# Are you still looking for one particular Birth/Baptism/Marriage/Death/Burial Record?

Tags: discussion, challenge

We have done this as a Topic Challenge before but I think it is time to dust it off and run it again:

> **Vital records that seem not to exist**?
>
> Things like elusive birth, death or marriage records...
>
> Every genealogist has at least one example!

If you are new to the site be sure to take our 2-minute [Tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Please try to ask about only one missing record per question and don't forget to summarize your research so far into finding that elusive record as context.

Sometimes as I write, or shortly after I post, a question I find that I solve it in the process.  If you are the same don't be afraid to self-answer and self-accept your answer as per an earlier discussion on [Are we happy to see more self-answered questions?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/are-we-happy-to-see-more-self-answered-questions)

Also, we are running out of challenge topics so I encourage everyone to try to contribute a new one at [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off)

Comment: Just an idea: what about adding WTC to the beginning or the end of the tags, to make it more obvious they are a temporary tag?

Comment: @JanMurphy I have ended up dispensing with special tags for these challenges.  Our question volume is low enough to make spotting them easy any way so it is one less instruction to give people who may be new to the site and have just spotted it Featured in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

The **first** time that this challenge ran  (during the week up until 7 Nov 2014), the following questions about Missing Vital Records were asked:

- [Finding death record of John Annear (b.1750, Probus; m.1775, Gwennap) in Cornwall?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6604/finding-death-record-of-john-annear-b-1750-probus-m-1775-gwennap-in-cornwal)
- [When, where and to whom was William Henry Rouse born in about 1832 near Truro (or Redruth), Cornwall?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6606/when-where-and-to-whom-was-william-henry-rouse-born-in-about-1832-near-truro-o)
- [Finding birth/baptism/marriage record for Priscilla who married printer Henry Hughes probably about 1810 in Breconshire, Wales?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6611/finding-birth-baptism-marriage-record-for-priscilla-who-married-printer-henry-hu)
- [Seeking marriage record for James Slight and Elizabeth Boyd from late 1820s probably near Haddington, East Lothian, Scotland?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6612/is-there-baptism-record-for-william-slight-who-was-probably-born-1829-30-near-ha)
- [Finding online parish records for churches in Werdau, Saxony, Germany](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6616/finding-online-parish-records-for-churches-in-saxony-germany)

These 5 questions attracted only 2 answers (neither yet accepted :-() and so this week my encouragement award goes to someone new to our site who contributed the first question:

[image: profile for Jason Pascoe at Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange, Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history]

Comment: If we are going to repeat challenges, perhaps your opening "during the week the challenge ran" should be modified to include the date: "during the week of day month year".

Answer (score 0):

The **second** time that this challenge ran  (during the weeks leading up to 30 May 2015), the following questions about Missing Birth/Baptism/Marriage/Death/Burial Records were asked:

- [Finding baptism record near Marystow, Devon, for Harriet Palmer in about 1770?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9209/finding-baptism-record-at-marystow-devon-for-harriet-palmer-in-about-1773)
- [In the early 1900s, were Chicago deaths recorded by government?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9214/in-the-early-1900s-were-chicago-deaths-recorded-by-government)
- [Finding information on ancestors who lived in the Polish Borderlands (Kresy)](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/finding-information-on-ancestors-who-lived-in-the-polish-borderlands-kresy)
- [Searching for birth record for Lucy Pratt Stowell b circa 1813 Norfolk/Plymouth Co, MA](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/searching-for-birth-record-for-lucy-pratt-stowell-b-circa-1813-norfolk-plymouth)
- [Is George Bismark Foster the son of Dr James W Foster and Arabella?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9237/is-george-bismark-foster-the-son-of-dr-james-w-foster-and-arabella)
- [Seeking birth record for John Shaw Mckay born 1915 in Glasgow, Lanark, Scotland](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/seeking-birth-record-for-john-shaw-mckay-born-1915-in-glasgow-lanark-scotland)
- [Finding documentary evidence for father of somebody born 1903 in Kentucky, USA?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9245/finding-documentary-evidence-for-father-of-somebody-born-1903-in-kentucky-usa)

These 7 questions attracted 6 answers (one already accepted) and so this week my encouragement award goes to someone new to our site who contributed two questions:

[image: profile for Anon123 at Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange, Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history]