# Is there a census record that you've looked and looked for but cannot find?

Tags: discussion, challenge

> **Census Records that seem not to exist?**
>
> Every genealogist has at least one example of an elusive census
>   record!
>
> Feel free to ask for help on how to locate your most elusive census
>   record from any census in any country.  You know, the one you've
>   looked for repeatedly, know must be there somewhere and just cannot
>   find.  And, if we are not flooded with questions, by all means feel
>   free to ask about your other elusive census records too!

If you are new to the site be sure to take our 2-minute [Tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Don't forget to give a very brief summary of your research so far into trying to answer your own question - it saves us simply covering the same ground.

Here is a link to [previous questions tagged as `census-records`](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census-records?sort=frequent) that may offer ideas about what details to include in your question and the types of answers you may be able to receive.

Sometimes as I write (or shortly after I post) a question I find that I solve it in the process.  If you are the same, don't be afraid to self-answer and self-accept your answer as per an earlier discussion on [Are we happy to see more self-answered questions?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/are-we-happy-to-see-more-self-answered-questions)

Also, we are running out of challenge topics so I encourage everyone to try to contribute a new one at [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off)

---

This answer became:

- a Topic Challenge in June 2015
- Weekly Topic Challenge #5:

using this Meta Q&A:

- [Is there a census record that you've looked and looked for but cannot find?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/whats-your-most-elusive-census-record)

Comment: Also a missing census record question (but perhaps not worth holding up as an example): http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3922/finding-people-who-have-moved-within-the-same-geographical-area

Comment: I suppose as long as I don't ask about the 1890 US census...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the week the challenge ran, the following questions about Elusive Census Records were asked:

- [Where was Mary Ann Harper in the 1881 England census?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6649/where-was-mary-ann-harper-in-the-1881-england-census)
- [Were James Smyth Stacy and family in London, Devon or elsewhere for 1841 Census?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/were-james-smyth-stacy-and-family-in-london-devon-or-elsewhere-for-1841-census)
- [Where was Charlotte Hancock, usually of Lewannick, Cornwall, for the 1851 Census?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/where-was-charlotte-hancock-usually-of-lewannick-cornwall-for-the-1851-census)
- [Where was Matthew Nettell, of Illogan, Cornwall, for the 1861 Census?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/where-was-matthew-nettell-usually-of-illogan-cornwall-for-1861-census)

These 4 questions attracted 3 answers (2 have already been accepted) and even though I am the organizer, I think my effort to ask three questions for the second successive week may be worth recognizing:

[image: profile for PolyGeo at Genealogy & Family History Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history]

Answer (score 0):

The second time this challenge ran, the following question about an elusive Census Records was asked:

- [Looking for Francois Paul Leon Mouchet in 1930 census in Los Angeles?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9354/looking-for-francois-paul-leon-mouchet-in-1930-census-in-los-angeles)

It has received 5 votes so far and an answer (that has received 3 votes so far).