# Are you interested in Canadian genealogy and Family History?

Tags: discussion, challenge

If you have Canadian ancestors and some unsolved questions regarding their genealogy and your family history here's your chance to try and clear them up!

The latest Topic Challenge, which will run for about two weeks comes from @JanMurphy:

> One thing I have neglected so far is research in **Canada**, in part
>   because the I am missing a lot of 'obvious' records like passenger
>   lists that weren't kept during the period I need them. I would love to
>   see more Q/As about Canadian research so I can learn more about record
>   groups I may have missed.

To whet your appetite for the task our current top two [frequently visited questions on Canada](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada?sort=frequent) are:

- [Sources for Border Crossings between Toronto and Chicago in early 1890's?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/sources-for-border-crossings-between-toronto-and-chicago-in-early-1890s)
- [Identifying Lemuel K. Preston's 1830s-era birth place of "Broome, L. C."?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/how-to-better-identify-lemuel-k-prestons-1830s-era-birth-place-broome-l-c)

and for those looking to answer rather than ask, we currently have two [unanswered questions on Canada](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canada?sort=unanswered):

- [How to find someone from Canada who has not been heard of since about 1939?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/how-to-find-someone-from-canada-who-has-not-been-heard-of-since-about-1939)
- [Birth Record for Son of Scottish Surgeon Attached to Canadian Regiment During US Occupation](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7878/birth-record-for-son-of-scottish-surgeon-attached-to-canadian-regiment-during-us)

If you are new to the site be sure to take our 2-minute [Tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Don't forget to give a very brief summary of your research so far into trying to answer your own question - it saves us simply covering the same ground.

Sometimes as I write, or shortly after I post, a question I find that I solve it in the process.  If you are the same don't be afraid to self-answer and self-accept your answer as per an earlier discussion on [Are we happy to see more self-answered questions?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/are-we-happy-to-see-more-self-answered-questions)

Also, we are running out of challenge topics so I encourage everyone to try to contribute a new one at [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off)

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could help here. Living in Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada and doing genealogy all my life, you would think I'd know something.

But my experience is limited to specific areas of Saskatchewan and Manitoba, ship arrivals in Halifax, and bits of info from the Canadian Archives and Censuses that pertain to Saskatchewan and Manitoba.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of this topic challenge three new questions related to it had appeared:

- [Finding residence information for Toronto in the 1840s?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/need-resources-for-toronto-in-the-1840s)
- [What is "Canada E" in the 1860 US Federal Census?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9265/what-is-canada-e-in-the-1860-us-federal-census)
- [Other 'non-loyalist' Immigration to Canada following American Revolution from the US](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/other-non-loyalist-immigration-to-canada-following-american-revolution-from-th)

They attracted only one answer, that has been accepted, so thank you to those who participated.